# How to generate an AR query that returns record A, excluding any that are attached to record B of a certain type

Tags: sql, activerecord

My relevant DB tables are an Invoices table and an Advances table with a has_many relationship (an invoice has many advances). I am trying to generate an ActiveRecord query that will return all invoices EXCEPT those that are attached to any advances of advance_type: :pre_settlement.

My current query:

```
  @invoices = invoices.left_joins(:advances).
      where.not('advances.advance_type': :pre_settlement).
      distinct.
      order(period_ends_at: :desc, created_at: :desc)
```

This produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT "invoices".* FROM "invoices" LEFT OUTER JOIN "advances" ON "advances"."invoice_id" = "invoices"."id" WHERE "advances"."advance_type" != $1  [["advance_type", "pre_settlement"]]
```

The problem is that in situations where the invoice has multiple advances, as long at least one advance is `advance_type != :pre_settlement` that invoice will be included. I want to make sure that any invoices that are attached to even one pre_settlement advance will be excluded.

Comment: That LEFT JOIN returns regular INNER JOIN result. The WHERE clause's advance_type condition should be in the ON clause to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: @jarlh that would still only eliminate any rows where the advance_type is presettlement, leaving any where that same (invalid) invoice is attached to a different advance type

Comment: Do you want a LEFT JOIN or an INNER JOIN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general solution to this would be something like this:

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
  scope :has_flagged_comments, -> { joins(:comments).merge(Comment.flagged) }
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  scope :flagged, -> { where(status: "flagged") }
end

# Posts that don't attract bad behavior:
Post.where.not(id: Post.has_flagged_comments)
```

I may have some of my syntax off as I don't have a test dataset to run this on, but this is the general approach. This would generate a query something like this:

```sql
select … from posts
where id not in (
 select id from posts
 left join comments on comments.post_id = posts.id
 where status = "flagged"
)
```